# Parameter reference works on lambda but not in function

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, reference

I'm not too sure if I'm just completely forgetting basics here but can someone please tell me why after changing the flag only T1 stops?

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void job(const bool &flag)
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    while (flag)
    {
        std::cout << "Working T2" << '\n';
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    bool flag = true;
    std::thread t1([&flag]()
                   {
                       using namespace std::chrono_literals;
                       while (flag)
                       {
                           std::cout << "Working T1" << '\n';
                           std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
                       }
                   });
    std::thread t2(job, flag);

    std::cin.get();
    flag = false;
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

my understanding is that both are accessing the same piece of memory as the flag is being passed as a reference, so the job function should not be creating it's own copy of the flag, and should just access the same flag passed to it, is this not how this works?
Many Thanks

Comment: `std::thread t2(job, flag);` takes the parameter by value. The reference `job` receives is the reference to some internal storage maintained by `t2` into which `flag` is copied, not to the original `flag` variable. Make it `std::thread t2(job, std::ref(flag));`

Comment: Somewhat related, this program exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race - an unsynchronized access to a non-atomic object.

Comment: Any particular reason it only works with std::ref and not just a &?

Comment: Again, the issue is not with how `job` takes its parameter, but with how `std::thread` takes its parameters - by value by default, one uses `std::ref` to instruct it to take one by reference instead.

Comment: @ThomasBriggs When you pass an argument to `std::thread` it **takes ownership** of that argument because the thread might not start until a while later. Taking ownership of a reference would be *suprising*. Surprises are bad, so it requires using `std::ref()` to make the intent explicit..

Answer (score 0):

```
std::thread t2(job, flag);
```

This makes a copy of `flag` and passes that copy to `job()`. In order to use a reference, you need to use `std::ref`:

```
std::thread t2(job, std::ref(flag));
```

But why is this a requirement?

There's a few different ways to look at it, but here's a fairly straightforward counter-example:

```
void job(const bool& val);

int main() {  
  // No problem
  job(true);
  
  // Would be broken if std::thread didn't make a copy.
  std::thread my_thread(job, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so all the relevant information is in one place:

> why after changing the flag only T1 stops?

**Firstly**, because [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) copies its arguments by value, as you see from the linked documentation. So, the existing code is *guaranteed not to work*

If you fix this by wrapping the argument in `std::ref` as suggested, you reach the second problem (which is actually already present in your lambda version), which is:

**Secondly** because using this reference in another thread this way is a data race. So, the existing code is *guaranteed not to be portable*. It may happen to work for some platforms, some of the time, but it's still sloppy.

The flag should be a `std::atomic<bool>` (or `std::atomic_flag`) instead.